# SSRS Multi-Column Report Page Breaking Incorrect

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I've seen this posted years ago without a solution (as early as 2006), and with a newer 2016 report builder, maybe there is one now.

I have a report that has 3 columns that is to be printed on sheets of labels with 3 columns and 10 rows.  Each page of the sheet should have separate groups on it.  SSRS recognizes page breaks as column breaks however, so the grouping mixes on pages.  For example, say Category 1's information takes up 15 labels, all of column 1 and half of column 2.  A page break should mean that Category 2 starts on the next sheet of labels, but instead it starts on the same page as Category 1 on column 3.

Has a workaround been discovered to make this behave correcly, such as a flag, expression, or another setting?

Comment: I guess you could use some sort of logic to pad out with empty spaces when a group finishes in the middle. I.E. you already know how many labels you have on a page.. you can possibly take each category and mod that by the number of labels.. and append the result as blank rows to that category.. this should, in theory push the second group out to a new page..I'd do this at the data layer of course

Comment: @Harry do you have an example of this you can provide?